# to make loop if in element (/view/element/myfile.ctp) for to check if is admin or member

Tags: cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.1

I try to make loop if in file '/view/top-menu.ctp' (top-menu.ctp)...To display links according to the roles
example:

`If (roles == Admin) {  // I m looking for this condtion ?
<a href='…..'> Admin </ a>
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
In your loop condition you can write:

<?php if($variable['Model']['field'] == 'Admin'){ ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>Controller/function"> Admin </ a>

<?php }else if($variable['Model']['field'] == 'User'){ ?>

<a href="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>Controller/function">User</ a>

<?php } ?>
```